# Inefficient solution to finding palindrome

Tags: java, algorithm

**Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two n-digit numbers and return mod 1337**

Input from n=1 to n=8

```
public class Solution {
    public int largestPalindrome(int n) {
    int[] arr = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000};
    int max_palindrome = 0;
    for(int x = arr[n] - 1; x >= arr[n - 1]; x--){
        for(int y = arr[n] -1; y >= arr[n - 1]; y--){
            int maybe = x*y;
            if(is_Palindrome(maybe)){
                if(maybe > max_palindrome){
                    max_palindrome = maybe;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max_palindrome%1337;
    }

    public boolean is_Palindrome(int toCheck){
        char[] charArr = String.valueOf(toCheck).toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++){
            if(charArr[i] != charArr[charArr.length - 1 - i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This fails at `n=4` because of time issues. What can I do?

Comment: You don't need to convert the string to a `char[]`. That requires allocation of an array each time, and copying the string into it (on top of creating the string). Just use `charAt`. Mind you, that's just faffing around the edges.

Comment: Since `x*y == y*x` you can have a shorter inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the inner loop to start from the current outer loop value:

```
 01234
0*****
1 ****
2  ***
3   **
4    *
```

This will give you all pairs possible. That is you need (n * (n+1))/2 runs instead of n^2.

In your check palindrome function, you make a similar superflous work:

You check all characters from right to left for equality with the counterpart, but you can stop at the middle. Thus you need only half the compare operations you need now.

You also can skip checking the number altogether, if maybe is smaller than your current found max palindrome. Currently you check first, then you decide if it is bigger.

The final strike in runtime performance is, to stop calculating the row as soon as you reach a product `maybe` that is smaller than your current candidate palindrom. Since you count backwards, this row is lost: You will not reach a higher product with smaller numbers.

Your code also has a flaw. The product of high n values is larger than max integer and will create negative values. You must switch the code to longs.

```
public class Solution {
    public long largestPalindrome(int n) {
        if( n==0 ) return 1;

        int[] arr = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000};
        long max_palindrome = 0;
        for (long x = arr[n] - 1; x >= arr[n - 1]; x--) {
            for (long y = x; y >= arr[n - 1]; y--) {
                long maybe = x * y;
                if (maybe <= max_palindrome) {
                    break;
                }

                if (is_Palindrome(maybe)) {
                    max_palindrome = maybe;
                    System.out.printf("Palindrome: %dx: %d, y: %d%n", max_palindrome, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
        return max_palindrome % 1337;
    }

    public boolean is_Palindrome(long toCheck) {
        String cand = String.valueOf(toCheck);
        final int len = cand.length() - 1;
        final int maxIdx = len >> 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxIdx; i++) {
            if (cand.charAt(i) != cand.charAt(len - i))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the question :-)

Comment: "That is you need n! runs instead of n^2." - n! would actually be greater than n^2.  Luckily, you don't actually need n!.  It's 1+2+3+4+5..., not 1*2*3*4*5... .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the questions parameters dictate int and not longs

Comment: You can return int, but you need long for the product. At least in java 

Comment: Can you break in the `is_Palindrome()` condition? Any smaller value of y cannot be a larger product for the same value of x right?

Comment: @John3136 This happens automatically, because the palindrome will only be tested, if your maybe is bigger than the current palindrome.

Comment: @thst Got it. Breaking in the if probably saves you one about 3 operations (total, not per loop), so it is a pretty low value optimization... Another low value one (from C) - store arr[n-1] in a variable and use the var in the for loop condition. Using both of these saves about .2 of a second (approx 4%) in my "fully optimised C version". I know I'm getting obsessed. Someone help me ;-)...

Answer (score 2):

@thst has given pointed out some good optimisations. I've tried his solution, but it still runs very slow at n=5.

If profiling shows that using a string is slow (or you just don't want to do it) then you can modify is_Palindrome() to use integer operations instead. I won't show all the code, just the outline and tips:

```
public boolean is_Palindrome(long toCheck)
{
    // TODO
    // Figure out how many digits toCheck has and the value of the
    // most significant. e.g. "2345" has a length of 4 and the value 
    // of the most significant is 1000.
    // You may know these from your array and so can pass them in...

    while(length > 1)
    {
        // In example 2345: left = 2, right = 5.
        long left = toCheck / msdValue;
        long right = toCheck % 10;

        if (left != right)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // TODO
        // So they matched eh? You need to remove the digits already checked
        // from toCheck. Least significant is easy: / 10.
        // Most significant needs to use the msdValue (and something else)

        // You stripped out 2 digits, so your length and the size of
        // the msdValue need to change to reflect that.
        //
        length -= 2;
        msdValue /= 100;
    }

    // We've done early return as soon as we found a pair of digits that
    // didn't match, so if we get here all the digits matched and so we've
    // got a palindrome.
    //
    return true;
}
```

Ok. Putting some of the comments into the answer:

I implemented @thst's solution in C. Time for n=7 was around 45 seconds for a string version using `sprintf`. When the string calculation is replaced with my implementation above the time is consistently around 16 seconds - lets call it a 3 time speedup.

I then replaced my loop that caclulates the length with a function that does a table lookup.

```
int numDigits(long num, long* msdValue)
{
    if (num >= 1000000000000000) { *msdValue= 1000000000000000; return 16; }
    // and so on...
```

This reduced the time to a consistent 7.5 seconds - so more than twice as fast as "plain maths" and 6 times faster than the naive string implementation.

Replacing `numDigits()` with an inplace version rather than a function call makes a small but measurable difference: Consistently runs in the 5.9s - lets call it 6 secs.

**Remember: This is in C and so results may not hold for Java.**

All in all, a very handy reminder that there is more than one way to do things, and small things can matter if you do them often enough...

Comment: You skipped the interesting part :-) Deciding the length requires comparing to 10-potencies (1/10/100/...). You need some kind of table for that to be fast. For n=7, the max value is 10^14, the min is 10^12. The comparisions on the char is the same amount than on the numerics itself. You gain the string conversion. For the amount of comparisions left, I judged, that the gain is not worth the time. Would be interesting, if it actually makes a significant difference, though.

Comment: Interesting parts left as an exercise for the reader ;-) OPs code knows the msbValue, so can leverage off that avoid a loop to figure out the length etc (table lookup would be faster I know). This is just a way to do it without strings. My first attempt would be strings too unless someone told me they weren't allowed.

Comment: Op will multiply two values from length n. So the length of the resulting product will vary between 2n and 2(n-1). Correct me if I am wrong, you gain the difference between creating the string and finding the length. Creating the string in will require 2n operations. The compare on the string is n operations, while the compare on the number is 5n numeric operations plus some magic x that you left out, I think you need 2 more (== 7n). Would be really interesting if you actually gain something here.

Comment: C implementation of algorithm on Solaris using a loop to calculate the length. 9000000 calls takes approx 30 seconds for the int version and 48 seconds for a sprintf string version. I know C isn't Java so results are worthless. It also depends on the length of the number - the longer the slower, so the data may be invalid (I did use the same numbers for both, but they may be too short to realistically match OPs case - I'm using my own driver, not OPs)

Comment: @thst Assuming I can break the y loop after the fist palindrome is found, C impl for your solution is approx 45 seconds on my solaris VM. using strings and about 16 seconds for my "maths based" approach. This is based on averaging a handful of runs - nothing formal, but at least in C using maths is around 3 times faster than using strings.